# How to show Drop Down box its mapped value instead of its key in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, antd

I am new to the react and I am using ant design for my UI. Recently I am facing some issues regarding with the drop down.

Problem:
I have a page where I am showing drop down I can show the value in the drop down, on selection of any value I am storing its Key in the redux.
So when I go foreword and come back to the same page drop down shows the key instead of its mapped value. I am using key as number and mapped value as alphabet.

Tried:
When I use the key as an alphabet every thing works fine and I can see the mapped value even when I go back and forth.

```js
...
...
...
{getFieldDecorator("name", {
  initialValue: this.props.partner.name                
  (
     <Select showSearch >
    <Option
      key=1
      value="Partner 1"
         />
    <Option
      key=2
          value="Partner 2"
        />
     </Select>
  )}
...
...
...
```

Can any one help me how I can show the mapped value when I am using key as number in the drop down box?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pass value to key you can pass it to value. and here is one example of it

```
{getFieldDecorator("name", {
  initialValue: this.props.partner.name                
  (
   <Select showSearch >
    <Option value=1 > Partner 1 </Option>
    <Option value=2 > Partner 2 </Option>
   </Select>
  )
}
```

I hope this will help you. Also you can look antd documentation.

Answer (score 0):

what you are storing (key in your case) in *`redux`* , is used by the *`Select`* as the value and not the *key*.

So , what you can do is either store the value itself (better) or do the mapping of key to the value by managing a separate Data Structure like *object*.